# Using SAPUI5 libraries locally

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I've inherited a project that references sapui5 libraries as a remote resource:

```
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.84.31/test-resources/sap/ushell/bootstrap/sandbox.js"></script>
        <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.84.31/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

Occasionally, our corporate network fails to download some of the js files of the SAPUI5 framework (net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR errors or takes half a minutes for each js file). As a workaround, i would like to reference the SAPUI5 framework JS libraries locally. It appears that there is no way to download just the JS framework files (similar to JQuery). I would have to examine the browser requests and manually save the JS files locally.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the UI5 Build tooling it will give you the opportunity the create
self-contained packages that include all used UI5 libraries.

see [UI5ers Buzz #42: UI5 Evolution – The Build and Development Tooling](https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-blogs-by-sap/ui5ers-buzz-42-ui5-evolution-the-build-and-development-tooling/ba-p/13409771)